# Rails 3.1 Possible Bug in Asset Pipeline and Uglifier

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.1, heroku, asset-pipeline, sprockets, uglifyjs

I ran into a problem deploying on Heroku do to a failure in the rake task

```
rake assets:precompile
```

At the bottom is the error I get if I integrate

- Rails 3.1
- Jquery calendar: https://github.com/themouette/jquery-week-calendar
- Twitter bootstrap

The error happens from uglifier.

I suspect that problem could be related to the inclusion of many localizations for the calendar.

I worked around the error by setting:

```
# Compress JavaScripts and CSS
config.assets.compress = false
```

I was not able to examine the files as the temporary files are cleaned up. I also could not get the debugger in RubyMine to stop at a breakpoint.

Any ideas if this is a bug? Any way to get the temporary files to not get deleted? Any way to make the RubyMine debugger work on the rake task (yes, tried the obvious, using EAP 112-291.

> rake assets:precompile:all RAILS_ENV=production RAILS_GROUPS=assets
>   rake aborted! Unexpected character '' (line: 21454, col: 0, pos:
>   641761)
>
> Error
>       at new JS_Parse_Error (/tmp/execjs20111231-15374-1fve7h4.js:497:22)
>       at js_error (/tmp/execjs20111231-15374-1fve7h4.js:505:15)
>       at parse_error (/tmp/execjs20111231-15374-1fve7h4.js:596:17)
>       at Object.next_token [as input] (/tmp/execjs20111231-15374-1fve7h4.js:839:17)
>       at next (/tmp/execjs20111231-15374-1fve7h4.js:943:37)
>       at Object.semicolon [as 1] (/tmp/execjs20111231-15374-1fve7h4.js:986:38)
>       at prog1 (/tmp/execjs20111231-15374-1fve7h4.js:1527:28)
>       at simple_statement (/tmp/execjs20111231-15374-1fve7h4.js:1123:35)
>       at /tmp/execjs20111231-15374-1fve7h4.js:1031:35
>       at /tmp/execjs20111231-15374-1fve7h4.js:1510:32

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You will probably find that one of you js files has a syntax error somewhere. This could be a missing semicolon at the end of a block, or some other minor problem. Often browsers will  still load the js and it will work, but uglifier cannot compress it with those errors. I would start looking in the localisation files first.

One way to find out which file contains the error is to re precompile locally with a minimal set of files and add things one by one until it breaks. If it is due to a missing semicolon, the breakage will the second-last file you added.

Comment: It's so annoying  that the uglifier doesn't tell me the blooming line number of the error!  I mean, c'mon.... isn't that what compilers are meant to do?  For me unfortunately it was a library I downloaded with about 3000 lines, so I'm now spending ages cutting out bits of the library and re-compiling until I find the bit that's got the syntax error.

Answer (score 3):

Mine precompiled after I removed a stray "debugger" statement. Woops.

Answer (score 2):

If anyone reading this thread encounters issues with unicode characters or "invalid byte sequence in UTF-8" in your rails app, try putting this in your production.rb file:

```
# override default uglifier options so we don't mangle unicode
  config.assets.js_compressor = Uglifier.new(output: {ascii_only: true})
```

In my case, the uglifier was converting strings in my javascript like `\udbff` into UTF-8 characters `í¯¿` which ultimately was breaking some unicode regex. (This was happening with turbo-sprockets and codemirror but you might encounter it anytime your javascript relies on ASCII representations of unicode characters.)

Comment: In my case, it turned a bunch of unicode string keys like "\u24B6" into "?" after compiling select2 diacritics, resulting in a bunch of duplicate keys. This caused a syntax error: "Duplicate data property in object literal not allowed in strict mode."

Answer (score 0):

The I18N file "jquery-ui-i18n.js" has a bad character before each comment.

Looking at the first two lines with "more" in a shell, shows the wrong character:

```
<U+FEFF>/* Afrikaans initialisation for the jQuery UI date picker plugin. */
/* Written by Renier Pretorius. */
```

After having removed this character it works.